# Using `ava` test runner for functional testing

Tags: api-testing, rest-api

This question is to get a recommendation from the community, what framework/library they mostly use for testing their APIs (REST) in JavaScript.

I stumbled upon https://github.com/avajs/ava, **would like to hear from experts**,

On the first look, it seems to be good for Unit testing. But I'm planning to use it for API testing, it can be used to do API testing as well.

I have also looked at RestAssured and Frisby. Haven't settled on anything yet.

The ideal framework should be able to run the API tests in a distributed fashion ( I love with Selenium and Grid)

Hope this question belongs here.

Comment: I've personally used Postman and SoapUI. Both of the tools helped me to achieve my project's testing.